How to get the value of text box with button click
I am using multiple text boxes as buttons.  Each text box has a different value. When I click on any text box a macro runs. I want to use the textbox value as a variable in the macro. I am unable to set the specific clicked on text box value as Variable1.
Private sub msoTextBox_Click()
   Variable1 = Field1.Value
End sub

